# Creating a triangle with OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glsl, glfw

I  am having trouble with my C++ code for an OpenGL program that is supposed to create a 2D triangle and keep receiving this error message:

```
Error! Fragment shader failed to compile.
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version directive must occur in a shader before anything else.
Error! Shader Program Linker Failure.
```

I have tried putting the code from lines 13-27 before the const char* APP_TITLE line (line 8) but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

What can I do to generate this 2D triangle?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

const char* APP_TITLE = "Texturing a Pyramid";
const int gwindowWidth = 800;
const int gwindowHeight = 600;
GLFWwindow* gWindow = NULL;

const GLchar* vertexShaderSrc =
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;"
"void main()"
"{"
"    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);"
"}";

const GLchar* fragmentShaderSrc =
"version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 frag_color;"
"void main()"
"{"
"    frag_color = vec4(0.35f, 0.96f, 0.3f, 1.0);"
"}";

void glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
void showFPS(GLFWwindow* window);
bool initOpenGL();

int main()
{

    if (!initOpenGL())
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW intialization failed." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // Top Vertex
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Right Vertex
       -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f // Left Vertex
    };

    GLuint vbo, vao;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertexShaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    GLint result;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, sizeof(infoLog), NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Error! Vertex shader failed to compile." << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragmentShaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, sizeof(infoLog), NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Error! Fragment shader failed to compile." << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vs);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fs);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, sizeof(infoLog), NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Error! Shader Program Linker Failure" << std::endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
    {
        showFPS(gWindow);
        
        glfwPollEvents();

        glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
        
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSetKeyCallback(gWindow, glfw_onKey);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

bool initOpenGL()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* gWindow = glfwCreateWindow(gwindowWidth, gwindowHeight, APP_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    if (gWindow == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(gWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "GLEW initialization failed." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    return true;
}

void glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void showFPS(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    static double previousSeconds = 0.0;
    static int frameCount = 0;
    double elapsedSeconds;
    double currentSeconds = glfwGetTime(); // returns # of seconds since GLFW started, as a double 
    
    elapsedSeconds = currentSeconds - previousSeconds;

    // limit text update 4 times per second
    if (elapsedSeconds > 0.25)
    {
        previousSeconds = currentSeconds;
        double fps = (double)frameCount / elapsedSeconds;

        double msPerFrame = 1000.0 / fps;

        std::ostringstream outs;
        outs.precision(3);
        outs << std::fixed
            << APP_TITLE << "   "
            << "FPS: " << fps << "   "
            << "FrameTime: " << msPerFrame << " (ms)";
        glfwSetWindowTitle(window, outs.str().c_str());

        frameCount = 0;
    }

    frameCount++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the revision-1 [mcve]!  Those help immensely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fragmentShaderSrc` is missing a `#` ([U+0023 NUMBER SIGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)) in front of `version`:

```
"version 330 core\n"
 ^ note lack of #
```

Should be:

```
"#version 330 core\n"
 ^ note the #
```